# Running a shell command with execlp() from a string

Tags: c, linux, shell

Im trying to get my program to run a shell command from using `exelp()`. The user basically inputs a shell command which is stored and then executed by `exelp()` in a new shell .

Lets say the user inputs "**ls -l /bin/??**", which in turn captured by the variable `command[]`. How can I get this text string to be executed within a shell envionment.

The closest I have come to understand how to do this would be by doing `execlp("/bin/sh", "-c", command, (char *)NULL);` , where `/bin/sh` launches a mini-shell, `-c` enables shell to take strings, and second last argument is simply the string captured earlier. I know that `system()` is an option here but I want to do this with execlp for educational purposes.

What is it I´m missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no call in the `exec` family that takes a single string of arguments.  Your options are either a list of strings or an array of strings.  This means you need to parse your input string into separate arguments yourself before using one of the `exec` calls.  You did that by hand above.  Now you need to do it programmatically.

Comment: You can only use `execlp()` in a very limited set of circumstances; you must know the number of arguments at compile time.  You normally use `execvp()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are asking how to expand inside your C program a shell word into an argument subsequence. See [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)

Then consider [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) and [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html)

You should realize that when you type `ls -l /bin/??` it is the shell's duty to expand the `??`; the `/bin/ls` program is [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)-ed with the *result* of that *expansion done by the shell* ...

Alternatively, you could leave that to a `/bin/sh -c` shell started by [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) or [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) functions. If you pass to these functions some user inputs, beware of [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) and quote appropriately any user input.  Imagine that you run a string made of `ls -l` and some user input; if a malicious user gives `a; rm -rf $HOME` as a file name you'll be sorry if your don't quote it (because without precautions your program will build the `ls -l a; rm -rf $HOME` command string then will pass that string to `system` or `popen` and then disaster happens).

Answer (score -1):

You are putting a `const char**` instead of a `const char *` as tird argument

try `execlp("/bin/sh", "-c", "ls", "-l", "/bin/", 0)`
or create an other char** with "-c" as first argument and then use `execv`

I guess it's compiling since the two arguments are pointer but they are of the wrong type

**EDIT**

when you call execlp as you do.
as you say command is a `const char[]`, but in the definition you need to put only `const char*`
it's as if you call the function like that

```
execlp(const char*, const char*, const char **, char*) //wrong obviously
```

so you have two solutions.
The first using bin/sh -c it's to concat all the argument and pass it to execlp

```
int main(int argc, char **av)
{
  char  **args;
  int   i;
  char  *cmd;
  size_t size;

  args = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (4));
  args[0] = "sh";
  args[1] = "-c";
  i = 1;
  size = 0;
  cmd = malloc(1);
  *cmd = '\0';
  while (i < argc)
    {
      cmd = realloc(cmd, strlen(cmd) + 1 + strlen(av[i]));
      strcat(&(cmd[size]), av[i]);
      size += strlen(cmd);
      strcat(&(cmd[size]), " ");
      size++;
      i++;
    }
  args[2] = cmd;
  execvp("/bin/sh", args);
}
```

But it's not very clean

The best way (and the more logical for me) I think it's to find the address of the binary so in your case /bin/ls and then pass it using `execvp`

something like:

```
char *get_binary_addr(const char* fct)
{
  return "/bin/ls"; //ofc you will parse your /bin to find binary addr
}

int main(int argc, char **av)
{
  char  **args;

  args = malloc(sizeof(char*) * argc);
  memcpy(&(args[0]), &(av[1]), argc * sizeof(char*));
  execvp(get_binary_addr(av[0]), args);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexis. What do you mean I'm using a `const char**` in the third argument? Do you mean the NULL pointer? Also, I explicitly need to run the command from a single string that contains the entire command. Hence the "ls", "-l" ... is not an option for me.

Comment: The 1st snippet misses to set `args[3] = NULL;`.

Comment: The 2nd snippet misses to pass the NULL-pointer `args[argc+1]`  acting as a sentinel at all.

Comment: And on top of this `execlp()` needs to get `(char*) 0` passed as last argument. The cast matters.